# How can I use roles in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, authorization, roles

In my application I have these roles:
Guest, User, Owner and Admin

I would like to use some kind of authorization where Admin can use all of the endpoints, while Owner can use all the functions that a User have. How should I achive this? What are good pratices?

Comment: Do you have everything else setup though ? Like your entities, database, UserDetails, etc ?

Comment: Yes I do, for now this is the only part which is not crytal clear.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Tell if that clears out your ambiguity, otherwise let me know all your security related classes and such...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your securityConfig file setup and everything then all you need to do is permit access to different pages by different user roles, you do it as follow in your `SecurityConfig` class:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/homePage").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/userPage").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        .antMatchers("/adminPage").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/homePage")
            .failureUrl("/loginPage?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")                
        .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/loginPage?logout"); 

}
}
```

As you can see, home page is accessed by any user with ROLE_ADMIN or normal user (USER_ROLE) roles...
If you see the adminPage can only be accessed by users with ROLE_ADMIN roles...

Comment: So it's that simple? It's a better practice to write down in the Security file which role can access to an endpoint?

Comment: Hence why it is called Spring Security ? If you wanna use your own functions like if user_role == A_Certain_User_Role, they can access a certain page, then why use Spring Security ? Spring Security is there for us to get rid of all the boilerplate code that is very repetitive and time consuming. Long story short, yes it is that simple.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use methods security. First of all, you need to enable method security, you can do this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) //THIS IS THE KEY
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

After enable, you can easily use security by method and user, like this:

```
@GetMapping("/ativas")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER') and #oauth2.hasScope('read')")
public List<YourObject> findAll(){
    return service.findAll();
}
```

This is a short answer.

Answer (score 1):

First add Spring Security dependency to your pom.xml. Now use a class to configure Spring security by extending webSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Make sure you add @Configuration and @EnableWebSecurity annotations. Have a look at code below. This should help.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(id).password("{noop}" + pwd).roles("USER").and().withUser(admin_id).password("{noop}" + admin_pwd).roles("ADMIN", "USER");
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.
    csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN").
            and().httpBasic();

}
```